# Lnd - how to open a double-funded channel

Tags: lightning-network, lightning-network-daemon

I know about `lncli openchannel`, however this means I will open a (bidirectional) channel with my peer, but initially just my side will have some balance. Let's say I agree with a collegue running another lightning node that we both want to have some initial balance. I'd expect to use something like `lncli halfopenchannel` on both sides and after we both do it the funding transaction and everything aftewards will get created. Same as TCP SYN this is prone to DoS and there needs to be some timeout. Of course the workaround is that he gives me some funds and I then push some of them directly to his side, but that's not really the most optimal approach. Any other possibility? Does any other lightning implementation address this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you ask for is called dual funded channels as both peers would found the channel. All implementations will eventually have this feature as it has been agreed to include it to BOLT 1.1. I think c Lightning has done most progress on dual funded channels (in particular Lisa neigut has a branch working on it)